# How to programatically extract XMP Tags added by WLPG?

Tags: python, windows-7, exif, xmp, exiftool

I tried both exif.py (in Python) and ExifTool (just for debugging on command-line).

No matter what I do, I'm unable to extract image Tags or Rating added to a JPEG by Windows Live Photo Gallery.

I found similar reports of this issue here:
http://kott.fm/tomek/forums/topic/xmp-not-picking-up-wlpg-tags/

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex. Please send me a sample file and I'll take a look. One reason could be that XMP data is stored as XML in a separate APP marker. EXIF data is stored in APP1 as a TIFF style header. A normal EXIF tool will not "see" the XMP data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered there was some sort of caching scheme gone rogue within WLPG and it was not writing out the XMP tags to the image files. Deleting the "Pictures.pd6" file and rebooting solved the problem.